# Need assistance in solving Amazon Lambda Forbidden Exception error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-iot

I am creating a lambda server that will query the IoT Core for the shadow state of a thing. The code that I implemended followed this example here:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=221549

Here is the current state of my lambda server code (simplified to save space):

```
import logging
import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client('iot-data', region_name = 'us-east-1')
response = client.get_thing_shadow(thingName = 'Battery', shadowName = 'Voltage')

    class SimpleIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
        def can_handle(self, handler_input):
            # type: (HandlerInput)->bool
            return ask_utils.is_intent_name("Simpleintent")(handler_input)
        
        def handle(self, handler_input):
            #type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
            #deviceID = ask_sdk_core.utils.request_util.get_device_id(handler_input)
            
            streamBody = response["payload"]
            rawDataBytes = streamBody.read()
            rawDataString = rawDataBytes.decode('utf-8')
            
            jsonState = json.loads(rawDataString)
            LogMessage("Json", jsonState)
            
            #LogMessage("Json", jsonState)
            voltageValue = 12
            speak_output = "It has a voltage of " + str(voltageValue) + " volts"
            return(
                handler_input.response_builder
                    .speak(speak_output)
                    
                    #.ask("add a repromt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond")
                    .set_should_end_session(False)
                    .response
                )
```

When I go to run the code, I am getting the following error:

An error occurred (ForbiddenException) when calling the GetThingShadow operation: None

Not sure what is going on with the code. Did I setup everything correctly?

Note:

I did create a IAM policy that allows the get_thing_shadow where I specify the ARN to the shadow. For the policy I only selected the permission for the get_thing_shadow.